# How to assign fields in Django

Tags: django

```
test = Email(user = 1, kind="test mail", time=now, sent=now, status=1)
test.save()
```

`1` is incorrect. How to set here admin user?

**Cannot assign "1": "Email.user" must be a "User" instance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the user `id`, get the user instance with corresponding `id`.

```
email_user = User.objects.get(id = 1)
```

Then pass the user instance in creating `Email` instance.

```
test = Email(user = email_user, kind="test mail", time=now, sent=now, status=1)
test.save()
```

#### OR

```
Email.objects.create(user = email_user,
                     kind = "test mail",
                     time = now,
                     sent = now,
                     status = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It expects a user object as input, not an integer, try this:

```
emailuser = User.objects.get(username='theusername')
test = Email(user = emailuser , kind="test mail", time=now, sent=now, status=1)
test.save()
```